# Problems installing socket.io

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I’m developing a program that requires `Node.js` and `Socket.io`. After attempting to install both, I found no inconvenience with “Node.js” but run into an error when inputting `npm install socket.io` in CMD:

```
C:\Users\otori\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_module s\ws\build\binding.sln : MSBUILD : error MSB3411: Could not load the Visual C++ component "VCBuild.exe". If the component is not installed, either 1) install the Microsoft Windows SDK for Windows Server 2008 and .NET Framework 3.5, or 2) install Microsoft Visual Studio 2008.
```

error code: `error MSB3411`

It would appear my `node.js` or my CMD cannot find `VCBuild.exe` and are asking for me to install VS2008, which I already have installed (I’ve also tried with VS 2010).

Any help or guidance is deeply appreciated, im using Windows 8 x64 and node.js v0.10.1

Comment: So, did you try installing .NET Framework 3.5?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to dig up an old question, but your question is the first result when I searched for "Socket.io VCBuild"

The solution I found, after stumbling around was :

npm install socket.io --msvs_version=2012

or

npm install sqlite3 --msvs_version=auto